# Androidmanifest build error about receiver within a service

Tags: android, android-intent, android-studio, android-service, android-broadcast

I'm trying to build an application with gradle>assembleRelease on AndroidStudio but I have an error:

Error:(31) Error: The  element must be a direct child of the  element [WrongManifestParent]

the concerned code is :

```
  <service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.xx.ServiceCalendar">
        <receiver android:name="com.example.xx.ServiceCalendar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ALARM_DL" />
                <action android:name="ALARM_PARSE" />
                <action android:name="ALARM_NOTIF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </service>
```

But the problem is if I put my receiver directly under my application, it die when an alarm is set.

What is the best practice about this?
Thanks in advance

**UPDATE :**

I understand that receiver and Services are two differents things, here is a part of my ServiceCalendar class :

```
public class ServiceCalendar extends Service {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;
    BroadcastReceiver mReceiver;


public void startAlarm() {
    manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    int interval =7200000;


    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("ALARM_DL");
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);


    manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);

}

private final BroadcastReceiver receiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        if (arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_DL"))
        {
            //action 1
        }
        else if (arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_PARSE")){
             //action 2
        }
        else if(arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_NOTIF")){
            //action3
        }

    }

};
}
```

As you can see I'm trying to run a Broadcastreceiver in my service, but i don't know how to set it up in the manifest.

Is there any way to do this (I think so as I've seen some exemples)?

Comment: You can not put receiver inside service in manifest.

Comment: receiver it self is enough  ..                                                            <receiver android:name="com.example.xx.ServiceCalendar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="ALARM_DL" />
                <action android:name="ALARM_PARSE" />
                <action android:name="ALARM_NOTIF" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

Comment: So if I only declare my class as a receiver, it will implicitly be also a service?

Comment: No, it will be a receiver only, Receiver and Service are two different thing. its like tea and vodka, dont compare them.

Comment: I understand that (I think), and I've updated my question with more info about what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to create a Service and a BroadcastReceiver separately and not create an inner dynamic BroadcastReceiver.

In AndroidManifest:

```
<service android:enabled="true" android:name="com.example.xx.ServiceCalendar">
</service>
<receiver android:name="com.example.xx.BroadcastReceiverCalendar">
  <intent-filter>
       <action android:name="ALARM_DL" />
       <action android:name="ALARM_PARSE" />
       <action android:name="ALARM_NOTIF" />
  </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Create 2 classes, 1rst service:

```
public class ServiceCalendar extends Service {
    private PendingIntent pendingIntent;
    private AlarmManager manager;

    public void startAlarm() {
        manager = (AlarmManager)getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        int interval =7200000;


        Intent alarmIntent = new Intent("ALARM_DL");
        pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);

        manager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,        System.currentTimeMillis(), interval, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

And 2nd BroadcastReceiver:

```
public class BroadcastReceiverCalendar extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context arg0, Intent arg1) {

        if (arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_DL"))
        {
            //action 1
        }
        else if (arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_PARSE")){
             //action 2
        }
        else if(arg1.getAction().equals("ALARM_NOTIF")){
            //action3
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: I rewrote my app like that and it seems to be working, thank you*.